# Connecting Symfony website to Amazon relational database

Tags: mysql, symfony

I am working on a symfony website and I want to connect it to a remote RDS on amazon on which i will be running some Select queries to fetch some data every time page refreshes.

Is there an easy way to do so? I was reading something about doctrine but I didn't get it how to get it to use a remote database. Is it possible to do without using doctrine?

Comment: Yes, it's very easy - every single tutorial about symfony and database and SQL focus on MySQL, so you shouldn't have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS is a meta-layer to manage the database server itself. I assume you want to create a database, e.g. in MySQL, on Amazon RDS and use this database with Symfony and Doctrine.

If this is true, it is very simple: In your app/config/parameters.yml file, you have various `database_*` parameters. Just set the `database_host` to the IP address or domain of your DB server as provided by Amazon, set the correct user/password/port, and you're ready to go.